# SharePoint 2013, enable TLS 1.2 , SQL Server 2008 R2 native client, unavailable

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, tls

I am trying to disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 with only TLS 1.2 enabled on my SharePoint 2013 FARM, windows server 2012 r2 standard.

I am following this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/SharePoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-and-ssl-support-in-sharepoint-2013#EnableTLS), where in 1.4 section "Install SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client update for TLS 1.2 support ", the [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4343220/this-hotfix-is-no-longer-available) provided isn't available for download.

Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Native Client for 2008 and 2008 R2 with TLS 1.2 support is now available again.

[SQL 2008 and 2008 R2 TLS 1.2 SQL Native Client updates not available in Windows Catalog](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57606)

Answer (score 1):

Try the  [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=16978) and expand the instruction section,Now search for "2008 R2 Native Client" or this is the direct link for 64bit package:

"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188401&clcid=0x409"

Comment: That is very old. I did install SP3 on all SP servers and my current version is a lot higher than the one that comes with above feature pack 10.50.1600.1.

Comment: then that client should be there already. did you test?

Comment: Client is there, to turn off TLS 1.0 and 1.1, MS said, i need to install a hotfix, which isnt available for download now (Links i have given i my question). and hence i couldnt able to turn off TLS 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: typically, when you have the latest updates then old one already packaged in it.  as you mentioned you are on higher version, can you try to disable it?

Comment: i could able to disable it in registry, but my FIM (Forefront identity manager sync service )is breaking. It is not starting. and when i look for the error, they circle to install the hotfix.

Comment: UPA sync not working that is different issue, check this one, may be help on that...https://thesharepointfarm.com/2016/04/tls-1-2-support-workflow-manager-office-online-server/

Comment: I've opened [#433](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/OfficeDocs-SharePoint/issues/433) to address the KB download issue.